# Hamburger: Full screen navigation menu with UL as anchor container

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists

For long time I've been using an hamburger menu for my website, a full screen navigation overlay with absolute positioning where navigation open is (css) height=100% and close="0%". It is based on this tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_fullscreen_overlay.asp

It works fine if I use a DIV as container for the links: the open/close buttons works fine as well the anchor links which automaticaly get closed when they are clicked. Everything fine.

Thinking in accesibility-semantics I'd to use a UL as container instead of a DIV and here comes the problem. It turns out **only the first anchor link on the UL gets closed** on clicked as expected but not the others. I don't understand it.

The HTML

```
<section class="menu">

    <!-- close menu -->
    <button class="menu__close">
        <svg>...</svg>
    </button>

    <ul class="menu__content">
        <li><a href="#seccion-inicio">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#seccion-muestra">Muestras Web</a></li>
        <li><a href="#seccion-servicio">Servicios Web</a></li>
        <li><a href="#seccion-informacion">Información</a></li>
        <li><a href="#seccion-contacto">Contacto</a></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

The JS

```
document.querySelector(".menu__content a").onclick = function() {
    document.querySelector(".menu").style.height = "0%";
}
```

Comment: The querySelector looks like it only gets first element, try using jquery instead pure javascript https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't know about 'querySelectorAll' but alredy tried it and, anyway, it doesn't work, now not even the first anchor.

Comment: As another recommendation please consider to use bootstrap Navbar, you can see it here with hamburger similar to yours. Someone here can help resolve your issue though https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

> "The Document method querySelector() returns the **first** Element within
>   the document that matches the specified selector"

You could instead use querySelectorAll and then iterate over the collection to attach your click handler, JQuery not required.

```
let myAList = document.querySelectorAll(".menu__content > li > a")
for (var i = 0; i < myAList.length; i++) {
    myAList[i].onclick = function() {
        console.log("Click");
        document.querySelector(".menu").style.height = "0%";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Andrew. So this is exactly what I was looking for, it works perfectly!